# Printing from my .net app and the colors are wrong

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I am printing a custom generated image to 2 different color printers and the colors are off. If I save that same image out to a png, it looks fine and even prints fine via the photo viewer. I have set the PageSettings.PrinterResolution to the PrinterResolution on the PrinterSettings with a kind of "High" and nothing. Thanks.

[EDIT] also, if I print to a pdf via cutepdf the color is fine there as well

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the color depth of your generated image is different (16 bits vs 24 or 32)?

Comment: Is there a way to set the color depth on the printer? I am using the same code to generate both image saved and the image printed so they should be the same, I am thinking it has to be in the printer settings. but what do i know :)

Comment: You haven't said much about your graphic file or how it is being saved, but graphic formats generally have the bit depth encoded into them, so maybe the file is getting saved out as the wrong bit depth.  Your other file types are working properly, so I don't think it's printer settings.

Comment: When I save the image out I save it as a png and it is right, when I print I print from the image in memory, not the saved image, so I don't really know what depth that would be.

Comment: When you save it as a png, it forces color information into the file.  It seems pretty clear that whatever process you are using to print from memory is either missing color information, or imparting the wrong color information.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that changing the quality on the printsettings did the trick, it just didn't appear to until I got the image in better light.